# How do you include all the permutations' and combinations' probabilities of a given set of elements on python?

Tags: python, combinations, element, permutation

I have this code:

```
mainList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
itemList = []
for i in range(0, len(mainList)):
    strs = ""
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        strs += mainList[j]
    itemList.append(strs)

inp = ""
for y in mainList:
    inp += y

for i in range(0, len(inp)):
    prob = ""
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        prob += inp[j]
    if(itemList.__contains__(prob)):
        if len(prob) > 1:
            print("Probability of " + prob + " is 100%")
        else:
            print("Probability of " + prob + " is " + str(round((1/len(mainList))*100, 0)) + "%")
    else:
        print("Probability of " + prob + " is 0%")
```

It prints "Probability of a is 25.0%
Probability of ab is 100%
Probability of abc is 100%
Probability of abcd is 100%"

All I want is for someone to help me make sure that it prints all other permutations and combinations and their corresponding probabilities based on how the data is arranged. Like bc, cc, dd, aa, bb, bca, aaa and so on. Every kind of permutation and combination available up to the number of elements in a given set which is in this case 4.

Thank you for your time.

I tried using my own experience and was not sure where to begin.

It could perhaps be obvious but definitely not to me.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I would be grateful for a great correction to the code.  Again as I said, obvious to many. Oblivious to me.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Every kind of permutation and combination available up to the number of elements in a given set which is in this case 4. ..."*

Start by generating the list of all permutations.
The *[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools)* module conveniently provides a *[permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)* function.

```py
import itertools as i
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
V = []
for x in i.chain(*(i.permutations(l, r) for r in range(1, len(l) + 1))):
    V.append(list(x))
```

From here, divide the occurrence of *a* in *V*, by the total possible occurrences.
Note, the order doesn't matter here; *"abc"* is considered within, for example, *"cba"*.

```py
d = {}
N = len(V)
for z in range(N):
    for i, a in enumerate(V):
        M = 0
        n = len(s := {*a})
        for j, b in enumerate(V):
            if i == j: continue
            if not s == {*b}: M += 1
        d.update({tuple(a): M / N})
```

Output

```
a = 98.437500% = 0.984375
b = 98.437500% = 0.984375
c = 98.437500% = 0.984375
d = 98.437500% = 0.984375
ab = 96.875000% = 0.96875
ac = 96.875000% = 0.96875
ad = 96.875000% = 0.96875
ba = 96.875000% = 0.96875
bc = 96.875000% = 0.96875
bd = 96.875000% = 0.96875
ca = 96.875000% = 0.96875
cb = 96.875000% = 0.96875
cd = 96.875000% = 0.96875
da = 96.875000% = 0.96875
db = 96.875000% = 0.96875
dc = 96.875000% = 0.96875
abc = 90.625000% = 0.90625
abd = 90.625000% = 0.90625
acb = 90.625000% = 0.90625
acd = 90.625000% = 0.90625
adb = 90.625000% = 0.90625
adc = 90.625000% = 0.90625
bac = 90.625000% = 0.90625
bad = 90.625000% = 0.90625
bca = 90.625000% = 0.90625
bcd = 90.625000% = 0.90625
bda = 90.625000% = 0.90625
bdc = 90.625000% = 0.90625
cab = 90.625000% = 0.90625
cad = 90.625000% = 0.90625
cba = 90.625000% = 0.90625
cbd = 90.625000% = 0.90625
cda = 90.625000% = 0.90625
cdb = 90.625000% = 0.90625
dab = 90.625000% = 0.90625
dac = 90.625000% = 0.90625
dba = 90.625000% = 0.90625
dbc = 90.625000% = 0.90625
dca = 90.625000% = 0.90625
dcb = 90.625000% = 0.90625
abcd = 62.500000% = 0.625
abdc = 62.500000% = 0.625
acbd = 62.500000% = 0.625
acdb = 62.500000% = 0.625
adbc = 62.500000% = 0.625
adcb = 62.500000% = 0.625
bacd = 62.500000% = 0.625
badc = 62.500000% = 0.625
bcad = 62.500000% = 0.625
bcda = 62.500000% = 0.625
bdac = 62.500000% = 0.625
bdca = 62.500000% = 0.625
cabd = 62.500000% = 0.625
cadb = 62.500000% = 0.625
cbad = 62.500000% = 0.625
cbda = 62.500000% = 0.625
cdab = 62.500000% = 0.625
cdba = 62.500000% = 0.625
dabc = 62.500000% = 0.625
dacb = 62.500000% = 0.625
dbac = 62.500000% = 0.625
dbca = 62.500000% = 0.625
dcab = 62.500000% = 0.625
dcba = 62.500000% = 0.625
```